# java jLabel.setVisible not working

Tags: java

I want to detect number of monitors, and to display the same number of labels. But setvisible not working. InitialMonitorsDetection - I want to hide every label, in DetectMonitors - show some labels, but labels always visible. I am newbie in java, so sorry for dumb question. Thanks for any help. `

```
   public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
            }
```

`` public void InititalMonitorsDetection() {             
    Monitor1.setVisible(false);
    Monitor2.setVisible(false);
    Monitor3.setVisible(false);
    Monitor4.setVisible(false);
    Monitor5.setVisible(false);
    Monitor6.setVisible(false);
    Monitor7.setVisible(false);
    Monitor8.setVisible(false);
    Monitor9.setVisible(false);
    Monitor10.setVisible(false);

    }

    public void DetectMonitors() {

    JLabel[] ArMonitors;
    ArMonitors = new JLabel[11];
    ArMonitors[1] = Monitor1;
    ArMonitors[2] = Monitor2;
    ArMonitors[3] = Monitor3;
    ArMonitors[4] = Monitor4;
    ArMonitors[5] = Monitor5;
    ArMonitors[6] = Monitor6;
    ArMonitors[7] = Monitor7;
    ArMonitors[8] = Monitor8;
    ArMonitors[9] = Monitor9;
    ArMonitors[10] = Monitor10;

      GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.
      getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
      GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
      System.out.println(gs.length);

      for (int i=1; i <= gs.length; i++){
         ArMonitors[i].setVisible(true);
      }


      }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting     code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the    default look and feel.
     * For details see   http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */




    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainFrame().setVisible(true);

        }
    });


    MainFrame mainfr = new MainFrame();
    mainfr.InititalMonitorsDetection();
    mainfr.DetectMonitors();<code>` ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All UI operations need to be done through the Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT). You will need to remove this chunk:

```
MainFrame mainfr = new MainFrame();
mainfr.InititalMonitorsDetection();
mainfr.DetectMonitors();
```

An place it here (at the very least):

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         MainFrame mainfr = new MainFrame();
         mainfr.InititalMonitorsDetection();
         mainfr.DetectMonitors();
    }
});
```

Ideally though, you seperate your logic from your UI manipulation. The code segment above will run everything on the EDT, which, depending on the duration of the operations you are making, can have a negative impact on the responsiveness of your application.